# IOS - Firebase - This email is badly formatted

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, ios11

I'm working on an IOS project, after firebase integration. I'm getting this error "This email is badly formatted"
Here's code

```
 @IBAction func registerBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    if userNameTxt.text != "" && passwordTXT.text != "" {
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: userNameTxt.text!, password: passwordTXT.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(okButton)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {

                UserDefaults.standard.set(user!.email, forKey: "user")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            }


        })

    } else {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Kullanıcı Adı ve Şifre Gerekli", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okButton)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase makes an email validation when using *createUser*. Check that the string contained in the *userNameTxt* label is a valid email.

Comment: checked! this is a valid mail

Comment: can you show me an example of email you are getting through that label when the error pops up?

Comment: ranahaani@gmail.com

Comment: that's weird, it has a valid format, but the error you specified in the question comes from an invalid email format. Are you sure that by printing the *userNameTxt* label text it prints that valid email?

Comment: Hidden whitespace?

Comment: or maybe connected the password label to the email outlet, same with email one

Comment: it's done, I checked I'm using userNameTxt label as passwordTxt label. but now it's working file

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah upvote every answer or comment that has been useful please

Answer (score 2):

possible white spaces say 'String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();' make sure your trimming